# How to loop through an array of asynchronous jobs, and do them respectively?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

There is an array of jobs, say 'asking user to fill a form', 'issue an ajax request', etc.

I need to run these jobs one after another and finally call a `complete()` method.

Something like:

```
var jobs = [11, 22, 33, 44, ...];

for(var i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
   alert('Starting job #' + i);

   // chooseJobOperator shows a form and wait for user to <select> a member
   // and click save <button>
   async(chooseJobOperator(jobs[i]));

   alert('Job #' + i + ' is done, now for-loop will continue');
}

alert('All jobs are done now.');
complete();
```

When my job is for example showing a `prompt()` I don't need to do anything, since prompt is a synchronous method, but what about asynchronous methods?

Is it possible to do so using `jQuery.Deffered`?

Comment: You confused the terms "synchronous" and "asynchronous", I fixed it for you.

Comment: @fab thank you, I knew i may have confused them, because English is not my mother language :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
var jobs = [11, 12, 14, 15];
function doTheJob() {
    if (jobs.length === 0) {
        alert('All jobs are done now.');
        complete();
        return;
    }

    var job_Id = jobs.pop();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/DoTheJob",
        complete: function () {
            doTheJob();
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is better approach, but I would use `$.when` function for this. Here is an example of how it could look:

```
var jobs = [1, 2, 3];

var d = $.Deferred(),
    stack = [];

for (var i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
    stack.push(async(jobs[i]));
}

$.when.apply($, stack).done(function() {
    alert('All done');
});

function async(type) {
    alert('Starting job #' + type);
    return $.Deferred(function() {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert('Job #' + type + ' is done');
            self.resolve();
        }, 1000 * type);
    });
}
```

I used `setTimeout` as asynchronous operation.

http://jsfiddle.net/rs3Qv/1/

Comment: This is great but why you used an anonymous function inside `for`? BTW I chose RaraituL answer because my situation was not that complex to use $.Deferred.

Comment: I used it only for demonstration purposes, it's not relevant to the problem. And yes, RaraituL's answer is better, I would also prefere it, mine is just overcomplecated.